# download zip files by use of reader in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been working on this application that enables user to log in into another website, and then download specified file from that server. So far I have succeeded in logging on the website and download the file. But everything ruins when it comes to zip files.

Is there any chunk of code that could be helpful in reading the .zip files byte by byte or by using stream reader?

I m using `downloadfile()` but its not returning the correct zip file.

I need a method by which I can read zip files. Can I do it by using `ByteReader()`

The code used to download zip file is

```
string filename = "13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-05-22.zip";
            string filepath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\" + filename.ToString();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string user = "abcd", pass = "password";
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            try
            {
                client.DownloadFile("https://web.site/archive/13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-05-22.zip", filepath);
                Response.Write("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception ue)
            {
                Response.Write(ue.Message);
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. What's the problem you're having? It'd be very helpful if you could edit your question to include the code you're having problems with.

Comment: The question is still on in case anyone has any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer

```
WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
using (Stream input = objResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
using (FileStream output = new FileStream ("test.doc",
FileMode.CreateNew))
{
int bytesRead;

while ( (bytesRead=input.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
}
}
```

This is how i achieved it. Thanks everyone for ur help

Answer (score 4):

> is there any chunk of code that could be helpful in reading the zip files bytes by bytes aur by using stream reader.

Absolutely not. `StreamReader` - and indeed any `TextReader` is for reading *text* content, not *binary* content. A zip file is not text - it's composed of bytes, not characters.

If you're reading binary content such as zip files, you should be using a `Stream` rather than a `TextReader` of any kind.

Note that [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144193) and [`WebClient.DownloadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) can generally make things easier for downloading binary content.

Comment: I have already used `WebClient.DownloadFile`, but its of no use

Comment: In what way is it of no use? Does it throw an exception? Does it give you the wrong data?

Comment: @akhil: Well `WebClient.DownloadFile` *does* work, so the problem is elsewhere. However, you haven't given us *nearly* enough information to help you further. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: IT returns an invalid zip file. Can't just read the zip file or copy the contents of zip file into another zip file? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: OMG..... am I talking to THE Jon Skeet. I have read your book sir. Its an honor to talk to you. :)

Comment: @akhil: If it returns an invalid zip file, that suggests the server is responding with an invalid zip file. Take a close look at what it's downloaded and see how it compares with the original. Is it the same size, for example?

Comment: Actually server is responding with an invalid file of every type.
All the files are having content **The user has loggen in as BDE123**

Comment: **Virtual user _user_ logged in.**
This is the content of zipped file i just tried to download

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to downlaod zip file

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/DOWNLOAD/Filename.zip">Click To Download</asp:HyperLink>
```

Another solution

```
 private void DownloadFile()
    {


        string getPath = "DOWNLOAD/FileName.zip";
        System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

        byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file to download including its path.
        string filepath = Server.MapPath(getPath);

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;
            // Page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
            //   Page.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    Page.Response.Flush();

                    //  buffer = new Byte[1024];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            Page.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
                Page.Response.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: My File is on a remote server with url as https://web.site/abc.zip how things will work in this case

Comment: @akhil :u have to set getPath = "web.site/abc.zip"

Comment: i have tried it but it returns error **The given path's format is not supported. **